# How to draw or make custom route using MKMapView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I am trying to write an app that will show the route of a tram line. I have added the map, but I am having problems trying to find how to add this route to my app.

I have looked at MKOverlayRenderer and I think I have to add an image on top of the map to do this. There are some tutorials but they are outdated.

Can someone help me with this. Thank you

Comment: "I have looked at MKOverlayRenderer and I think I have to add an image on top of the map to do this." Exactly so. Read the docs on MKPolyline and MKPolylineRenderer. Good examples right in Apple's own docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner you should check the https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial.

example

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        lineView.lineWidth = 1

        return lineView
    }

    return nil
}


func addRoute() {
    mapView.deselectAnnotation(selectedAnnotationView.annotation, animated: true)
    let track = Track.GetAll()// to get list of coordinates you should write your own way to store
    if track.count == 0 {
        return
    }
    var pointsToUse: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

    var isTrackChanged = false

    for i in 0...track.count-1 {
        let x = CLLocationDegrees((track[i].Latitude as NSString).doubleValue)
        let y = CLLocationDegrees((track[i].Longitude as NSString).doubleValue)
        pointsToUse += [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(x, y)]
        if i > 0 {
            if pointsToUse[i-1].latitude != pointsToUse[i].latitude || pointsToUse[i-1].longitude != pointsToUse[i].longitude  {
                isTrackChanged = true
            }
        }
    }

    let myPolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &pointsToUse, count: track.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(myPolyline)     
 }
```

//model

```
class Track{
 var latitude =""
 var longitude=""
}
```